# AngularJS and GoogleMap

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

What I am trying is to get latitude and longitude dynamically as I move the marker on map. I found this solution:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt){

                          window.alert(evt.latLng.lat()+"---"+evt.latLng.lng());

                        });
```

but its not returning me new values for lat and lng

Here is my code given:

```
  $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(event, map) {

          var uluru;
          $scope.postGoogle = function(google){
              $http.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+google.address+google.city+google.state+google.zip+google.country+"&key="+google.apikey).
              then(function(response) {
                 $scope.latitute = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                 $scope.longitude = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                  uluru = {lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng};
                  map.setCenter({lat: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat, lng: response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng});
                  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">latitude and longitude</h1>'+
                  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                  '<Span>'+map.getCenter()+'</span>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '</div>';

                  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                      });

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: uluru,
                        map: map,
                        draggable:true,
                        title: response.data.results[0].formatted_address
                      });
                     /* marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                      });*/
                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(evt){
                         /* $scope.latitute =  evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3);
                          $scope.longitude = evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3);*/
                          window.alert(evt.latLng.lat()+"---"+evt.latLng.lng());
                          //window.alert(this.getPosition().lat());
                        });

                        /*google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(evt){
                            //$scope.latitute = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
                            window.alert(evt.latLng.lat());
                        });
                        */map.setCenter(marker.position);
                        marker.setMap(map);

              }, function(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
              });
            //window.alert(google.address+"------"+google.apikey);

          };






        var numTiles = 1 << map.getZoom();
        var projection = new MercatorProjection();
        $scope.chicago = map.getCenter();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little peice of JavaScript code what I used, to dynamically change lat and lng when marker is moved:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'position_changed', function() {

    lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
    lng = marker.getPosition().lng();

    $('#lat').val(lat);
    $('#lng').val(lng);

});
```

and bottom 2 lines are assigning value to html input, to see, that values are changed

Answer (score 0):

This is what I guess you are looking :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
        $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
        $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    }
  });
});
```